# iOS App - How to make and call runtime library/app

Tags: objective-c, ios, runtime

My iOS app has grown large and take long time to load. Lots of class in my application is not always needed, some may never been called at all depending on user. How can I split my application into several executable file and make the main application call/load them when needed (run-time)?

It's much easier if I can split my application into several executable because I can divide my team's workload into several executable with less dependency.

Comment: Are you sure that the load time is caused by actual code size (versus resource loading or other work that you do at startup)? You would have to ship a TON of code to have that make an appreciable load time difference.

Answer (score 3):

iOS does not support dynamically linking to anything but system-supplied libraries. Any other library must be statically linked into your application.

There's one way to make an end run around this: You can use interpreted code, provided it is shipped with your app. So, if you can split your app into an Obj-C controller and services layer driven by dynamically executed Lua code (for example), you could avoid loading code you never use.